# Symfony 2.3.7 form value from query result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, symfony

I had create a form from my Entity (use Symfony 2.3.7) and i have one problem:
i want put the query result in my form values.
Ex name : john (the name get in my table).
My form class is:

```
class form extends AbstractType{
   private $repository;
    private $idRistorant;

    public function __construct(EntityRepository $repository,$idRist)

    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->idRistorant = $idRist;
    }

 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('dataInser')
            ->add('username')
            ->add('password')
}

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'sgnamPanelBundle\sgnamPanelBundle\Entity\OdlineRistoranti'

        ));
    }


    public function getName()
    {
        return 'horizontal';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless that i'd not understand your question but by default When you create a form in a Controller ( i hope it's what you've done ) with an Entity that you have get in your DB. Symfony2 will fill the forms inputs with the values of the Entity.

Answer (score 0):

this is an example
in my controller:

```
// I want the getData() Result into value Form (<input type="text" value="username of //query Result">)

public function getData(){
     $repository = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('panelAdiminResturantBundle:OdlineRistoranti');
        $user = $repository->findBy(array('username' => $username,
            'passwordWeb'=>$password));
    }

    public function editResturantAction (Request $request){
        $form = $this->createForm(new OdlineRistorantiType());
        return $this->render('panelAdiminResturantBundle:Default:editResturant.html.twig',
                               array('form'=>$form->createView()));
        }
```

my form class

```
class form extends AbstractType{
   private $repository;
    private $idRistorant;

    public function __construct(EntityRepository $repository,$idRist)

    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
        $this->idRistorant = $idRist;
    }



    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder
                ->add('dataInser')
                ->add('username')
                ->add('password')
    }

        public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'sgnamPanelBundle\sgnamPanelBundle\Entity\OdlineRistoranti'

            ));
        }
```

my entity:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * OdlineRistoranti
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="odline_ristoranti")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class OdlineRistoranti
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="data_inser", type="date", nullable=false)
     */
    private $dataInser;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=20, nullable=true)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password_web", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    private $passwordWeb;
.
.
.
.
}
```